# How can I create curved view?

Tags: android

I am working on cinema tickets application and now I need to create a curved view with blur shadow  like this :
[image]

Is there a way of achieving this?

I have tried rotating image in x axis (-45%) but it is not what i need

Comment: You could insert an image.

Comment: but in that case it wont be responsive.

Comment: i tried using svg but it doesnt accept its shadow effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per @naggab's comment you should include image for this

but also I try to achieve this using below code

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <size
                android:width="450dp"
                android:height="110dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <size
                android:width="450dp"
                android:height="110dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="50dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="4"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:top="50dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-4"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: I will try and then reply

Comment: If this doesn't work you may try doing it with canvas.